# Drawing lines JavaScript - Click Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Im having issues with this code created. The problem im having is when i click to stop the line from drawing its has a 50% chance it will work first time However It only seems work correctly if you are doing straight lines only, but i want it to work from any direction and im not 100% sure why its not working line that.

(Im using 1.12.4 jquery as im adding this into WordPress thats what is runs off)

```js
$(function() {
  var x1 = null,
    y1 = null;
  var offsetX = 0,
    offsetY = 0;
  
  var moveLineId = "moveLine";

  function createLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, id) {

    var length = Math.sqrt(((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2)) + ((y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)));
    var angle = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI;
    var transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';

    offsetX = (x1 > x2) ? x2 : x1;
    offsetY = (y1 > y2) ? y2 : y1;

    var line = $('<div>')
      .appendTo('#demo')
      .addClass('line')
      .css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        '-webkit-transform': transform,
        '-moz-transform': transform,
        'transform': transform
      })
      .width(length)
      .offset({
        left: offsetX,
        top: offsetY
      });

    if(id != null) line.attr('id', id);

    return line;
  }

  $('#demo').click(function(event) {
      $(".line").removeAttr('id');
      var x = event.pageX,
        y = event.pageY;

      if (x1 == null) {
        x1 = x;
        y1 = y;
      } else {
        x1 = y1 = null;
      }
    })
    .delegate('.line', 'click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      x1 = y1 = null;
      return false;
    });
    

  $('#demo').mousemove(function(event) {
      var x = event.pageX,
        y = event.pageY;
        
      
      
      if (x1 != null) {
        $("#" + moveLineId).remove();
        createLine(x1, y1, x, y, moveLineId)
      } else {
        x1 = y1 = null;
      }
    })
    
});
```

```css
div.line {
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  height: 3px;
  /* Line width of 3 */
  background: #000;
  /* Black fill */
}

#demo {
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  height: 400px;
}

div.transforming-on-corner {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<h3> click two point to draw a line :</h3>
<div id="demo" class="wide">

</div>
```

Comment: The code snippet is working just fine for me.

Comment: Work fine, you've just to make sure when you click the second time to stop the line that your hand isn't still moving

Comment: The code doesn't work fine. Most of the time it will not take my second click to finish the line. Cerbrus answer works all the time tho.

Comment: Yes that what the comment says, you must stop your hand then click, not clicking while moving your hands (that called drag not click)

Comment: OP's problem statement was poorly worded - but @Cerbrus 's answer likely solves whatever issue he was having

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `click` events, listen to `mousedown` and `mouseup` events to start / stop drawing the line.

```js
$(function() {
  var x1 = null,
    y1 = null;
  var offsetX = 0,
    offsetY = 0;

  var moveLineId = "moveLine";

  // Use "mousedown" here so the start of a line is registered as soon as you press the mouse button.
  $('#demo').on("mousedown", function(event) {
      $(".line").removeAttr('id');
      var x = event.pageX,
        y = event.pageY;

      if (x1 == null) {
        x1 = x;
        y1 = y;
      } else {
        x1 = y1 = null;
      }
    })
    .delegate('.line', 'mouseup', function(event) {
      // Use "mouseup" here so the start of a line is registered as soon as you release the mouse button.
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      x1 = y1 = null;
      return false;
    });

  $('#demo').mousemove(function(event) {
    var x = event.pageX,
      y = event.pageY;

    if (x1 != null) {
      $("#" + moveLineId).remove();
      createLine(x1, y1, x, y, moveLineId)
    } else {
      x1 = y1 = null;
    }
  });


  function createLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, id) {

    var length = Math.sqrt(((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2)) + ((y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)));
    var angle = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI;
    var transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';

    offsetX = (x1 > x2) ? x2 : x1;
    offsetY = (y1 > y2) ? y2 : y1;

    var line = $('<div>')
      .appendTo('#demo')
      .addClass('line')
      .css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        '-webkit-transform': transform,
        '-moz-transform': transform,
        'transform': transform
      })
      .width(length)
      .offset({
        left: offsetX,
        top: offsetY
      });

    if (id != null) line.attr('id', id);

    return line;
  }

});
```

```css
div.line {
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000;
}

#demo {
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="demo" class="wide"></div>
```

Comment: OP's code snippet is already functional, but this does have the added benefit of being able to click-drag-release instead of clicking twice

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki / @Epicular: The problem was that the "click" event to stop drawing wasn't registering all the time. That's fixed by using `mouseup".

Comment: Why you think _the "click" event to stop drawing wasn't registering all the time_ ?!! the user that clicks sometimes with shake hands.

Comment: Because the "click" event doesn't fire if you move the cursor while clicking. Then `mousedown > mousemove > mouseup` are triggered.